# Хочу вывести несколько строк из массива в один div, выводит только много undefined; подскажите, что делать?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function examples(){
 var examples_arr = ["Example1","Example2","Example3"];
 var a, i;
 for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
    examples_arr[i]=a;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += a;
 }
}
```

Comment: Так у тебя `a` не определен. Ты записываешь в ячейку массива неопределенной значение, а потом его же и в док пытаешься вывести

Comment: Ты перепутал переменные местами. Вместо examples_arr[i]=a; нужно писать a=examples_arr[i];

Answer (score 1):

Если максимально использовать ваш код, то вот решение:

```
function examples () {
    var examples_arr = ["Example1", "Example2", "Example3"];
    var a, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a = examples_arr[i];
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += a;
    }
}
```

Но его можно оптимизировать. Например, не обязательно сохранять `examples_arr[i]` в отдельную переменную, можно сделать:

```
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += examples_arr[i];
```

К тому же вы жестко прописали конец цикла, правильнее будет получать это значение из длины массива:

```
var l = examples_arr.length;
...
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
```

С точки зрения быстродействия лучше не делать множественную вставку контента к тело страницы, т.к. это заставляет браузер ее перерисовывать. Лучше сначала сохранить контент в отдельную переменную, и после всех операций вставить ее контент. В итоге получаем:

```js
function examples () {
    var examples_arr = ["Example1", "Example2", "Example3"];
    var i;
    var l = examples_arr.length;
    var result = '';

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        result += examples_arr[i];
    }

    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += result;
}

examples();
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Действительно, можно сделать так, как указано в другом ответе:

```
function examples () {
    var examples_arr = ["Example1", "Example2", "Example3"];
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += examples_arr.join();
}
```

Но `[].join()` работает немного медленнее обычного суммирования строк и на больших объемах данных будет проигрывать в быстродействии.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам переменная `а`? Вы зачем то массиву присваиваете неинициализированную переменную `examples_arr[i]=a;`

```
function examples(){
   var examples_arr = ["Example1","Example2","Example3"];
   for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){
       document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += examples_arr[i];
   }
}
```

А вообще можно так сделать -

```
 document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = examples_arr.join('<br>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
examples_arr[i] = a;
```

Поменяйте местами право и лево:

```
a = examples_arr[i];
```

Comment: Еще присвоение `а` элементу нужно из цикла вынести